# simplified explanation on child themes?

Tags: themes, child-theme

I'm trying to create child theme for theme i'm using on my site...
I read lot's of articles about this, but can't find simple tutorial or simple explanation how to do it...

As i understand so far, if i copy (for example) loop.php file  to child theme, and change

```
if(is_home()) { 
  do something
}
```

from original loop file to

```
if(is_home()) { 
  do something else
  and do another more thing
}
```

my function will be executed and original function will be ignored?
Is this right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The child theme would over-ride the parent theme's loop.php if you made changes.

As for a simple tutorial I did a simple Google search, after a quick overview this one seems pretty simple: http://op111.net/53/.

Just in case you haven't been there, [here is the WordPress Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).